# How to provide Execution Context for jobExplorer.getJobExecution(job Id) when testing a single step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In the step that i`m testing has jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobId). It is returning jobExecution having ExecutionContext as null.How to provide this ExecutionContext when launching a step using JobLauncherTestUtils.launch(name,param,precookedContext)?

I tried Mocking the jobExplorer using @MockBean but i need to do with out using Mockito.

In Job:

```
@Bean(name="sampleWriter")
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWirter<String> sampleWriter(
#stepExecution.jobExecution.id long jobId){

RandomClass randomClass= RandomClass(jobExplorer.getJobExecution(jobId));
new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<String>
.name()
.writer(randomClass)
.build();
}
```

I expect to return jobExecution with ExecutionContext but the actual jobExecution returning null value.

Answer (score 1):

The `spring-batch-test` module provides several test utilities, two of them can be  useful in your case:

- [MetaDataInstanceFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/MetaDataInstanceFactory.html): This class allows you to create job/step executions with a "precooked" execution context. See [Mocking Domain Objects](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/testing.html#mockingDomainObjects) for more details and code samples
- [ExecutionContextTestUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/test/ExecutionContextTestUtils.html): This class allows to to get values from job/step execution context

> I'm not supposed to use mocktio framework.

With these classes, you can implement your test without using mockito.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sample test class using `MockitoJUnitRunner` and `@Mock`

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class TaskletTest {

        @Mock
        StepContribution stepContribution;

        @Mock
        ChunkContext chunkContext;

        @Mock
        StepContext stepContext;

        @Mock
        StepExecution stepExecution;

        @Mock
        JobExecution jobExecution;

        @Mock
        ExecutionContext executionContext;

        @Mock 
        JobExecution jobExecution

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            when(chunkContext.getStepContext()).thenReturn(stepContext);
            when(stepContext.getStepExecution()).thenReturn(stepExecution);
            when(stepExecution.getJobExecution()).thenReturn(jobExecution);
            when(jobExecution.getExecutionContext()).thenReturn(executionContext);
            MockitoAnnotations.init(this);
        }

        @Test
        public void yourTestCase() {
        //custom logic
        }

    }
```

Comment: @hanlak. Any specific reason. Mockito or PowerMock. I am not so sure about any other mocking frameworks. Thank you

Comment: I was given with the above task and I'm not supposed to mock the data